# Prevent bc from auto truncating leading zeros when converting from hex to binary

Tags: bash, bc

I'm trying to convert a hex string to binary. I'm using:

```
echo "ibase=16; obase=2; $line" | BC_LINE_LENGTH=9999 bc
```

It is truncating the leading zeroes. That is, if the hex string is `4F`, it is converted to `1001111` and if it is `0F`, it is converted to `1111`. I need it to be `01001111` and `00001111`

What can I do?

Comment: Do you want your answer to be pure `bc`?  There are a number of other languages you can do this at the command-line to convert a hex string to binary format with leading zeros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output from `bc` is correct; it simply isn't what you had in mind (but it is what the designers of `bc` had in mind).  If you converted hex `4F` to decimal, you would not expect to get 079 out of it, would you?  Why should you get leading zeroes if the output base is binary?  Short answer: you shouldn't, so `bc` doesn't emit them.

If you must make the binary output a multiple of 8 bits, you can add an appropriate number of leading zeroes using some other tool, such as `awk`:

```
awk '{ len = (8 - length % 8) % 8; printf "%.*s%s\n", len, "00000000", $0}'
```

Comment: I didn't think the output was incorrect. I just didn't want them cut off.

Thanks!

Comment: Binary and hex are frequently used to represent bytes, and in this context I think it does make sense to expect leading zeros. Decimal, on the other hand, is not used to represent bytes. So I do think it's reasonable to want `4F` to convert to `01001111`  in binary and `79` in decimal.

Answer (score 4):

You can pipe to `awk` like this:

```
echo "ibase=16; obase=2; $line" | BC_LINE_LENGTH=9999 bc | awk '{ printf "%08d\n", $0 }'
```

Comment: I am not sure this works for hex numbers that are bigger than a byte. The Python solution does work for that case.

Answer (score 3):

Pure Bash solution (beside bc):

```
paddy()
{
    how_many_bits=$1
    read number
    zeros=$(( $how_many_bits - ${#number} ))
    for ((i=0;i<$zeros;i++)); do
    echo -en 0
    done && echo $number
}
```

Usage:

```
>bc <<< "obase=2;ibase=16; 20" | paddy 8
00100000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in python:

```
line=4F
python -c "print ''.join([bin(int(i, 16))[2:].zfill(4) for i in '$line'])"
```

---

result:

```
'01001111'
```

Comment: If I had a stream if hex numbers, how would your PIPE the hex to this? I have a solution that works, but would like to see yours.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer because (1) It does the binary conversion and (2) It does the zero formatting.

Answer (score 0):

What's frustrating is the bc expects the input to be zero padded but doesn't provide a similar output option. Here's another alternative using sed:

```
sed 's_0_0000_g;    s_1_0001_g;    s_2_0010_g;    s_3_0011_g;
     s_4_0100_g;    s_5_0101_g;    s_6_0110_g;    s_7_0111_g;
     s_8_1000_g;    s_9_1001_g;    s_[aA]_1010_g; s_[bB]_1011_g;
     s_[cC]_1100_g; s_[dD]_1101_g; s_[eE]_1110_g; s_[fF]_1111_g;'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **seq** and **sed** to help you pād:

```
function paddington(){
  PADDLE=8; while read IN; do
    seq -f '0' -s '' 1 $PADDLE | \
    sed "s/0\{${#IN}\}\$/$IN/"
  done
}

bc <<< "ibase=16; obase=2; 4F; 1E; 0F" | paddington
```

The output:

```
01001111
00011110
00001111
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`printf`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) to left-pad the result with zeros if the result's length is not a multiple of four:

```
hex_nr=2C8B; hex_len=${#hex_nr}; binary_nr=$(bc <<< "obase=2;ibase=16;$hex_nr"); \
bin_length=$(( hex_len * 4 )); printf "%0${bin_length}d\n" $binary_nr
```

will result in

> 0010110010001011

instead of bc's output of

> 10110010001011